# How to send metrics of Hibernate Query Plan Cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How to send metrics of
getQueryPlanCacheHitCount()
getQueryPlanCacheMissCount()
to micrometer?

I tried to set spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
And created bean

```html
@Bean
MeterBinder hibernateQueryMetrics(EntityManagerFactory entityManager) {
    return new HibernateQueryMetrics(entityManager.unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class), "authorizationSvcSessionFactory", Tags.empty());
}
```

It sends hibernate statistics but without plan cache metrics